# Do until in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to stick the cursor of my coworker to the upper left corner of his Display. I'm doing it with a `do until` Loop. The only way to disrupt the script should be when the $FilePath has more childitems than "5". Any idea why this does not work?

```
$FilePath = "I:\TRANSFER"
$test = Get-ChildItem $FilePath
do {[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
$test.count}
until ($test.count -gt '5')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I got it. I can't put the Get-ChildItem into a Variable, because it only counts once. If I do it with commands, it works.

```
$FilePath = "I:\TRANSFER"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

do {
    [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
   }

until ((Get-ChildItem $FilePath).count -gt '5')
```

Comment: Barely any objects are updated once stored in variables. Get-Service is another example. Refreshing everything all the time would be a huge drain on resources so it leaves it to you to update what you need when you need it.